# The base class member function access child class member function directly?

Tags: android, c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

Is it possible that the base class member function can access child class member function directly?

I found the code from Androind, the **BufferQueue** inherits **BnSurfaceTexture**, and has one member function "requestBuffer".

In the base class **BnSurfaceTexture**, I found it just call requestBuffer directly.

How does the base class **BnSurfaceTexture** know the function "requestBuffer"?

Thanks

The base class member function:

```
status_t BnSurfaceTexture::onTransact(
    uint32_t code, const Parcel& data, Parcel* reply, uint32_t flags)
{
    switch(code) {
        case REQUEST_BUFFER: {
            CHECK_INTERFACE(ISurfaceTexture, data, reply);
            int bufferIdx   = data.readInt32();
            sp<GraphicBuffer> buffer;
            /* it call requestBuffer directly */ <--------
            int result = requestBuffer(bufferIdx, &buffer);
            reply->writeInt32(buffer != 0);
```

The child class declaration & implementation:

```
class BufferQueue : public BnSurfaceTexture {

private:
    virtual status_t requestBuffer(int slot, sp<GraphicBuffer>* buf);


status_t BufferQueue::requestBuffer(int slot, sp<GraphicBuffer>* buf) {
    ATRACE_CALL();
    ST_LOGV("requestBuffer: slot=%d", slot);
    Mutex::Autolock lock(mMutex);
    ...
    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the base class BnSurfaceTexture know the function "requestBuffer"?

This function must have been *at least* declared (it could have been defined with some default implementation) in the base class and it must be `virtual`.

So, at compile time, the compiler sees that such function exists.
The function call is resolved run-time. This is polymorphism.

---

Tiny example:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void f() { /* Base */ } // could be pure virtual
    virtual void g() { f(); };
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    virtual void f() { /* derived */ }
};
```

When you have

```
Base* pB = new Derived;
pB->g();
```

`g()` will call `Derived::f`;

Comment: Thanks Kiril ~ this is exactly what I want to know!!

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure the base class function is *declared*, and the derived class is *define before* definition of base class function *definition*. Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
    public :

    void call_derived ();
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public :

    void derived_fun ()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived class member function called!" << std::endl;
    }
};

void Base::call_derived ()
{
    static_cast<Derived *>(this)->derived_fun();
}

int main ()
{
    Derived dobj;
    dobj.call_derived();

    return 0;
}
```

However, this use of `static_cast` is unsafe, compiler won't complain if you try `call_derived` on an incomplete object. However, you can add an assertion `assert(dynamic_cast<Derived *>(this)`, at least in debug mode, for debugging purpose. Alternatively, you can declare Base class' constructor, destructor `protected`, to prevent creation of incomplete object, or attempting to destroy a derived object while the base is not polymorphic

However, the above code are not really common in real world. Other more advanced techniques exists, like CRTP, which also use `static_cast` and provide static polymorphism without `virtual` functions.

This answer may not be exactly what you want. It only shows that it is possible to call derived class members in base class even it is not defined in base at all. But to call it directly without any cast, you still need `virtual` functions.

Comment: Thanks Yan ~ Although this is not the exactly answer I want. But it is still a nice trick.